# Angular retry/retrywhen the Http request based on user inputs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

**after http request completed need collect the user pin and retry the same http request in angular 6 ?**

```js
this.appservice.setvalue(requested).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    if (response.val === 2) { // user don't have permission .. need to collect the another user pin which who having permission.
      // need to collect the user pin 
      this.getUserPin(); 
      // after collect the user pin.. recall the above same http this.appservice.setvalue(requested)  ..
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: does it continue until closing page ?

Comment: actually current user not having the permission . so it need to continue until user give valid pin..

Answer (score 0):

Try using filter and concatMap

```
this.appservice.setvalue(requested).pipe(
    filter(response => response.val===2),

    concatMap(() => {
        this.getUserPin();
        return this.appService.getOtherHttp()
    })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: i don't want to call new or different http call ...actually current user not having the permission . so it need to continue until user give valid pin.. the pin will send via in header .. after enter pin need to call same this.appservice.setvalue(requested)